# Getting Top Selling products from sql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get top selling products from a mysql database. I have tried to search some queries here but it does not work for me, so help would be appreciated.

I have a table `order_details`

[image]

I tried this query but it does not work:

```
select top 5 product_id, sum(quantity)
from order_details
group by product_id
Order by sum(quantity) desc
```

Comment: "*does not work for me*" falls miserably short of describing the observed behavior in terms of providing information needed to diagnose a problem. Is an error message returned? Too many rows? The rows returned differ from expected results? (shown in the question is what appears to be Microsoft Transact-SQL, syntax incompatible with MySQL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL uses `LIMIT`, not `TOP`, so perhaps this is what you wanted to do:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity
FROM order_details
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The `TOP` operator is Microsoft syntax (SQL Server and MS Access).

Comment: Here's an example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fjHUmR9s9XgpNzxx2Bu3Uu/0

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL use `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`

Here it the tutorial: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/sql-tutorial/sql-top-clause.php